# How to group associated results in rails includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, include

app/models/car_make.rb

```
has_many :car_models
```

app/models/car_model.rb

```
belongs_to :car_make
```

I want fetch all makes with their models . But models should be in grouped by name. I write the following query but

```
 makes = CarMake.includes(:car_models).group('car_models.name')
```

but it gives an error `Unknown column car_models.name`

Answer (score 1):

`.includes` loads the records in two queries. So in order to group on the joined table you need to reference it to force a join query:

```
makes = CarMake.includes(:car_models)
               .references(:car_models)
               .group('car_models.name')
```